# Forward and backwards diffusion for stable diffusion

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, stable-diffusion

I am trying to test a forward diffusion and backwards diffusion function. I am using the algorithm described on the following paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.11239

My test is to take an image. Pass it through the forward diffusion process. Then pass it through the backwards diffusion process. It is my expectation that I should get the original image. However, the denoising does not work and I get random image.

I use the following formula for forward diffusion:
[image]

and ddpm for backwards:

[image]

Below is my code test:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
MAX_NOISE_STEP = 20
# create a fixed beta schedule
beta = np.linspace(0.0001, 0.02, MAX_NOISE_STEP)

# this will be used as discussed in the reparameterization trick
alpha = 1 - beta
one_minus_alpha = 1-alpha
alpha_bar = np.cumprod(alpha, 0)
alpha_sqrt = np.sqrt(alpha)
alpha_bar = np.concatenate((np.array([1.]), alpha_bar[:-1]), axis=0)
sqrt_alpha_bar = np.sqrt(alpha_bar)
one_minus_alpha_bar = 1-alpha_bar
one_minus_sqrt_alpha_bar = np.sqrt(1-alpha_bar)



def stepNoise(key, x_t, t):
    np.random.seed(key)
    noise = np.random.normal(size=x_t.shape)
    betaT= np.take(beta,t)
    noisy_image =  ((1-betaT)**0.5) *x_t + betaT * noise
    return noisy_image,noise
# this function will add noise to the input as per the given timestamp
def forward_noise(key, x_0, t):
    np.random.seed(key)
    noise = np.random.normal(size=x_0.shape)
    noisy_image = np.take(sqrt_alpha_bar, t)  * x_0 + np.take(one_minus_alpha_bar, t)  * noise
    return noisy_image, noise
def ddpm(x_t, pred_noise, t):
    alpha_sqrt_t = np.take(alpha_sqrt, t)
    one_minus_alpha_t = np.take(one_minus_alpha, t)
    one_minus_sqrt_alpha_bar_t = np.take(one_minus_sqrt_alpha_bar, t)
    eps_coef = one_minus_alpha_t/ one_minus_sqrt_alpha_bar_t
    mean = (1 / alpha_sqrt_t) * (x_t - eps_coef * pred_noise)
    var = np.take(beta, t)
    z = np.random.normal(size=x_t.shape)

    return mean + (var ** .5) * z
    

#get feed
rng, tsrng = np.random.randint(0, 100000, size=(2,))
#read image and shape for batch
im = cv2.imread("10_29_2021.png")
im=np.reshape(im, (1,im.shape[0],im.shape[1],im.shape[2]))

im_c = ((im / 255.0) * 2 - 1)

noisyImage, noise = forward_noise(rng,im_c,MAX_NOISE_STEP-1)

x =noisyImage
for t in reversed(range(1,MAX_NOISE_STEP)):
    x= ddpm(x, noise, t)


x_image  = ((x + 1) / 2) * 255
noisyImage_image = ((noisyImage + 1) / 2) * 255

cv2.imshow('original',im[0])
cv2.imshow('Noisy',noisyImage[0])
cv2.imshow('denoised',x_image[0])
cv2.waitKey()
```